# Convert a CURL to Python - HTTPS POST

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to POST some data to an HTTPS server. It requires a very particular set of headers.  I'm able to complete the request, but I'm *unable* to do so in Python.

The curl:

```
curl -i 
-H "Authorization: Basic a2V5OnNlY3JldA==" 
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-H "Content-Length: 99" 
-H "User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LMY48Y)" 
-H "Host: test.example.com" 
-H "Connection: Keep-Alive" 
-H "Content-type: application/json" 
-d "grant_type=password&username=me%40example.com&password=abcd*1234&scope=scope1_services+scope1_data" 
"https://test.example.com/login/get/token/"
```

The Python is

```
import httplib, urllib
host = "test.example.com"
url = "/login/get/token/"

params = urllib.urlencode({"grant_type":"password", "username":"me@example.com", "password":"abcd*1234", "scope":"scope1_services+scope1_data" })

headers = {"Authorization": "Basic a2V5OnNlY3JldA==", "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length":"99", "User-Agent":"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LMY48Y)", "Host":host, "Connection": "Keep-Alive",  "Content-type":"application/json"}

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
conn.request("POST", url, params, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
```

I just end up with `400 Bad Request` and the error message

`{
   "error":"unsupported_grant_type",
   "error_description":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
}`

As far as I can tell, everything should be the same.

I've tried manually encoding the POST payload as `params="grant_type=password&user...` but I still get the same error.

Any idea what incredibly obvious thing I'm missing?

Comment: Check your `params`. There is a typo: `... "username":"username=me@example.com" ...`. Remove `username` from the value.

Comment: Sorry, copy&paste typo. Fixing it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is actually `Content-Type` not `Content-type`. Watch out the capital `T` there.

Also, I think you can remove these safely from the header:

```
"Content-Length":"99",
"Host":host,
"Connection": "Keep-Alive",
```

And, are you sure you need this? You are not posting any json here!

```
"Content-type":"application/json"
```

Comment: That's helped - although now I'm getting `'{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed."}'` I wonder if it's the way the `*` is being encoded...?

Comment: Yup, it was getting confused by the `%2A` as well - I manually wrote in `params="grant_type=password&username=me%40example.com&password=abcd*1234&scope=scope1_services+scope1_data" and it worked. Thanks for your assistance!